# How to write a shell script to perform below changes in the Parameter file

Tags: shell, informatica

I am looking to write a shell script that finds and replaces the parameter values every time a workflow is run. I am a beginner and trying to learn more about this.

For example

```
-$$mp_Custom_Filter_D_Prem=AND BLSB.BLSB_CREATE_DTM <= '2019-02-28'
--$$mp_Custom_Filter_D_LEP=AND convert(date,(substring(SBSR.SBSR_SOURCE,9,2)+substring(SBSR.SBSR_SOURCE,5,2)+substring(SBSR.SBSR_SOURCE,7,2))) <= '2019-02-28'
```

I have these 2 parameters in the file and I want the script to change the dates to advance a month and set its last day.

So far the date 2019-02-28 I would like the script to find the dates and replace it to 2019-03-31.

I have tried the below script and its not the same result

```
PRM_FIL_DIR=$1 PRM_FIL_NME=$2 LOG_FIL_DIR=$3 LOG_FIL_NME=$4 echo Begining of the log File > $LOG_FIL_DIR/$LOG_FIL_NME From=`grep '$$mp_Custom_Filter_D_Prem=AND BLSB.BLSB_CREATE_DTM <' $PRM_FIL_DIR/$PRM_FIL_NME | awk -F= '{print $3}'|uniq| sed "s/'//g" | awk '$1=$1' ` echo $From is Date value found in $PRM_FIL_DIR/$PRM_FIL_NME parameter File >> $LOG_FIL_DIR/$LOG_FIL_NME To=`date -d "$From 2 month -1 day" +%Y-%m-%d` echo $To is the value to be replaced in $PRM_FIL_DIR/$PRM_FIL_NME parameter File >> $LOG_FIL_DIR/$LOG_FIL_NME From_FNL="'$From'" To_FNL="'$To'" sed -i "s/$From_FNL/$To_FNL/g" "$PRM_FIL_DIR/$PRM_FIL_NME" echo Date values replaced >> $LOG_FIL_DIR/$LOG_FIL_NME echo End of the log File >> $LOG_FIL_DIR/$LOG_FIL_NME PRM_FIL_DIR=$1 PRM_FIL_NME=$2 LOG_FIL_DIR=$3 LOG_FIL_NME=$4 echo Begining of the log File > $LOG_FIL_DIR/$LOG_FIL_NME From=`grep '$$mp_Custom_Filter_D_Prem=AND BLSB.BLSB_CREATE_DTM <' $PRM_FIL_DIR/$PRM_FIL_NME | awk -F= '{print $3}'|uniq| sed "s/'//g" | awk '$1=$1' ` echo $From is Date value found in $PRM_FIL_DIR/$PRM_FIL_NME parameter File >> $LOG_FIL_DIR/$LOG_FIL_NME To=`date -d "$From 2 month -1 day" +%Y-%m-%d` echo $To is the value to be replaced in $PRM_FIL_DIR/$PRM_FIL_NME parameter File >> $LOG_FIL_DIR/$LOG_FIL_NME From_FNL="'$From'" To_FNL="'$To'" sed -i "s/$From_FNL/$To_FNL/g" "$PRM_FIL_DIR/$PRM_FIL_NME" echo Date values replaced >> $LOG_FIL_DIR/$LOG_FIL_NME echo End of the log File >> $LOG_FIL_DIR/$LOG_FIL_NME
```

I want the output to be the last day of the month i.e 2019-03-31 and actual output is 2019-03-29

Answer (score 1):

Try this flow,

```
lastmonth=$( date -d "-$(date +%d) days" +%Y%m%d)
currentmonth=$( date -d "-$(date +%d) days month" +%Y%m%d)

sed "s/$lastmonth/$currentmonth/g" filename.txt
```